# Plotting from excel to python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am new to python,pandas,etc and i was asked to import, and plot an excel file. This file contains 180 rows and 15 columns and i have to plot each column with respect to the first one which is time, in total 14 different graphs. I would like some help with writing the script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're new here - welcome! StackOverflow encourages users to post very specific questions, usually where you share what you've tried so far and point out a specific point where you're stuck. Very general questions such as this are too broad for the scope of the site. But the libraries @Piotrek linked to could be a great starting point for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these packages/ functions, you'll find some code on these websites and you can tailor it to your needs.

Some useful codes:

[Read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')
```

Code above reads an excel file to python and keeps it as a DataFrame, named `df`.

[Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df['column - x axis'], df['column - y axis'])
plt.savefig('you_plot_image.png')
plt.show()
```

This is a basic example of making a plot using matplotlib and saving it as `your_plot_image.png`, you have to replace `column - x axis` and `column - y axis` with desired columns from your file.

For cleaning data and some basics regarding DataFrames have a look at this package: [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `pandas.read_excel` ([Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)).

It will return a DataFrame-Object from where you can access your data in python. Make sure you Excel-File is well formatted.

```
import pandas as pd

# Load data
df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')
```